# Script is disabling inline editing in Visualforce

Tags: visualforce, javascript

Newbie dev here. Does anyone know why inline editing was disabled when I added the script below? The only reason I added it is because every time the page loads, the cursor moves to a specific field in the page, even though that was not last position of the cursor

```
<script>
    window.onload = function(){
        window.scrollTo(0,0);
    };
</script>
```

Not sure if you wanna see my Visualforce page since it's so long. I realize there is a similar question but it was not enough for me to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

The old-school handlers (e.g. onload) can only call one script at a time. When you assign a function to it, this causes the old handler to be bumped off. This is bad, because Visualforce needs to initialize some scripts in order to provide inline edit support (and other stuff).

If the order of execution is important, you should save the old handler before overwriting it:

```
const oldOnLoad = window.onload;
window.onload = function() {
  oldOnLoad && oldOnLoad.call(window);
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);
};
```

Ideally, you should be able to just add your own event listener using the now-standard technique:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);
});
```

This method is recommended, unless it somehow causes other things to break. You can even combine these two techniques to make sure nothing goes wrong:

```
const oldOnLoad = window.onload
window.onload = null; // will no longer be called by default
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  oldOnLoad && oldOnLoad.call(window);
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);
}
```

Comment: I believe best practice is to listen for `DOMContentLoaded` on the `document`.

Comment: @AdrianLarson It is almost always desirable, true. This is one of those rare situations where it may not be. DOMContentLoaded fires before load, and the default Visualforce script, if I recall correctly, sets focus on the first interactive input element, if any, located in the page, so the attempt to scroll up to the top might be overwritten by this autofocus logic. By forcing ourselves to go last, we win over whatever Visualforce may attempt to do.

Comment: @sfdcfox thank you for the answer, I understand now why it broke inline editing. Is there anything else I need to do besides copying your code? I tried all of them but the cursor still lands on the first `apex:inputField` which is the default behavior